# get product id from quote id - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, products, quoteitem, sales-quote

Hi need toget the product id of in a quote item.i have the qoute id with me and tried the below code but product id does not seem to display from the quote.

```
$quoteId=784;
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $quoteId)
->getFirstItem();
echo $pid = $quote[product_id] ;
```

Please help to get product id from quote id .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code

```
$quoteId=784;
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProductId();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Use below code for quote id arrays

```
$quoteIds = array(1,2,3,4);
$productId = array();

foreach($quoteIds as $quoteId){
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
    $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        $productId[] = $item->getProductId();
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($productId);
```

Comment: Hi can you help me to get product ids from array of quote ids

Comment: updated answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get product id in Magento 1.9

```
<?php 
    $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach($items as $item)
        { 
            echo $item->getProductId();
        }
?>
```